# will for/in loop exit a function after the loop?

Tags: javascript

```
function toggle() {
    overlays = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay");

    if (globalOpacityValue == 0.9){
        globalOpacityValue = 0;
    }else{
        globalOpacityValue = 0.9;
    }
    console.log("globalOpacityValue: " + globalOpacityValue);

    for (overlay in overlays) {
        overlays[overlay].style.opacity = globalOpacityValue;
    }
    console.log("toggle routine done!");

    tempStoreOnChangeArtificial();
    console.log("tempStoreOnChangeArtificial done!");
}
```

It seems to me that after the for/in loop, my function ends.

My toggle() never display "toggle routine done!", and obviously it doesn't run the  tempStoreOnChangeArtificial();

But it does things in the for/in loop.

why?

Comment: Probably you're getting errors.  Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your for loop is likely not running properly. In `overlays[overlay].style.opacity = globalOpacityValue;`, there is a chance that `overlays[overlay]` is `undefined`. Then you are trying to access the `style` property of `undefined`, which will throw an error.

Comment: So normally for/in loop doesn't ends a function? If that's the case I should run through my other codes.

Comment: Patrick Michaelsen: no. The things in the for/in loop is being done. But yeah, the console always said it can't access to style of undefined. But it still change the style normally so I didn't care

Answer (score 2):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array like object, which is not iterable with a [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```js
function toggle() {
    var overlays = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay"),
        i;

    if (globalOpacityValue == 0.9){
        globalOpacityValue = 0;
    }else{
        globalOpacityValue = 0.9;
    }
    console.log("globalOpacityValue: " + globalOpacityValue);

    for (i = 0; i< overlays.length; i++) {
        overlays[i].style.opacity = globalOpacityValue;
    }
    console.log("toggle routine done!");

//    tempStoreOnChangeArtificial();
    console.log("tempStoreOnChangeArtificial done!");
}

var globalOpacityValue = 0;
toggle();
```

```html
<div class="overlay">a</div>
<div class="overlay">b</div>
<div class="overlay">c</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You're trying to get an element from `HTMLCollection` using `in`.
- Use `overlay of overlays`.

---

```
function toggle() {
    overlays = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay");

    if (globalOpacityValue == 0.9){
        globalOpacityValue = 0;
    }else{
        globalOpacityValue = 0.9;
    }
    console.log("globalOpacityValue: " + globalOpacityValue);

    for (overlay of overlays) {
        overlay.style.opacity = globalOpacityValue;
    }
    console.log("toggle routine done!");

    tempStoreOnChangeArtificial();
    console.log("tempStoreOnChangeArtificial done!");
}
```

## Resources

- [`in operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)
- [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware that you can iterate over `document.getElementByClassName` using `for in` perhaps that's where the problem is, you may want to iterate over HTMLCollection like below:

```
function toggle() {
    overlays = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay");

    if (globalOpacityValue == 0.9){
        globalOpacityValue = 0;
    }else{
        globalOpacityValue = 0.9;
    }
    console.log("globalOpacityValue: " + globalOpacityValue);

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(overlays, function(overlay) {
        overlay.style.opacity = globalOpacityValue;
    });

    console.log("toggle routine done!");

    tempStoreOnChangeArtificial();
    console.log("tempStoreOnChangeArtificial done!");
}
```